# How to run multiple, parallel Rabbitmq/AMQP consumers in PHP and/or Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, php-amqp

I have a news-scraper/RSS-aggregation where I broadcast messages via this lib.:

https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/

I currently have 1 broadcaster/producer and 1 consumer.

Is there a way to have multiple consumers running in parallel via PHP? I know that PHP doesn't support this natively. It could be virtually done via cURL, but afaik cURL is mainly used for Network/Web-based requests.

So, is there any way for me to achieve this in PHP? Of course, I can do it in Python/Java, but my level is not that good in both.

Comment: What about using threads?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: I'll try to check it, though it's still an alpha extensions, and not well documented, I once read that there's a way to run parallel consumers for RabbitMQ in php, and Symfony2/Silex but I can't really find a link for anything like this.

Answer (score -2):

Do you really need messaging system like rabbitmq? IMHO [gearman](http://gearman.org/) is more appropriate solution for your task. [Getting starting](http://gearman.org/getting-started/) on gearman site is good to start with.

> It allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing

You can run and control several instances of workers in parallel with [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).
[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) is a good example how to install and configure supervisor

I use combination of these two services for the same task - I aggregate rss from several sources and it works like a charm

```
$gearman_top
 Queue Name   | Worker Available | Jobs Waiting | Jobs Running
---------------------------------------------------------------
 parseFeed    |               2  |           0  |           0
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It sounds like Gearman is just substituting the same role as RabbitMQ here (a queue), and the actual answer to the OP's question is to use Supervisor to control multiple workers ("consumers", in MQ parlance).

Comment: hm... not really sure if I'm in the stage of changing everything I'm using, I'd better go for a python multi-thread solution, than to migrate to Gearman, btw: I know gearman (just by name) but never tried it..